# Find general term of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

What would be the best way in finding a general term $a_{n}$, $n \geq 2$ for the recursive sequence $a_{n} = 3a_{n - 1} + 1$, where $a_{1} = 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let 
$$b_n=a_n+\frac 1 2$$
then

$$b_{n}=3a_{n-1}+\frac 3 2=3\left(a_{n-1}+\frac 1 2\right)=3b_{n-1}$$
so $(b_n)$ is a geometric sequence. Express $b_n$ using $n$ and the first term $b_1$ and then you find $a_n$.

**Edit** We have
$$b_n=3^{n-1}b_1=3^{n-1}\left(a_1+\frac 1 2\right)=\frac{3^n}{2}$$
so 
$$a_n=b_n-\frac 1 2=\frac{3^n-1}{2}$$

Comment: Can you explain why you let $b_{n} = a_{n} + \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: $(a_n)$ is called arithmetico-geometric sequence. The general method is to find $\ell$ such that $\ell=3\ell+1$ i.e. replace $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ by $\ell$ and then $b_n=a_n-\ell$ is a geometric sequence.

Comment: Ok, so now we have this, how do we find a general term for $a_{n}$?

Comment: You find the expression of $b_n$ (since it's a geometric sequence) and then $a_n=b_n-\frac 1 2$.

Comment: @user2850514 I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, note that $a_n = 3 a_{n-1} + 1 = 9 a_{n-2} + 4 = 27 a_{n-3} + 13,$ etc. So, you conjecture that $a_n = 3^{n-1} a_1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} 3^i=3^{n-1} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} 3^i.$ Now, you check that this works by induction.

Comment: Is there any way to express this without sigma notation?

Comment: $3^{n-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}3^{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}3^{i}=\frac{3^{n}-1}{2}$

Comment: I would have simply written the first few terms and noticed that they all were of the form $(3^n-1)/2$. At this point, an inductive proof should be easy.